# Правильно ли оформлена прямая речь?

Tags: пунктуация

Возможно ли такое оформление прямой речи?
Политолог Игорь Вершинин отмечает, что общество поровну разделилось между двумя векторами развития:

— Те, кто выступает за евразийский вектор, остались с чувством, что их воля была просто проигнорирована.

Или

Политолог Игорь Вершинин говорит, что общество поровну разделилось между двумя векторами развития:
— Те, кто выступает за евразийский вектор, остались с чувством, что их воля была просто проигнорирована.

В первом случае в конце авторских слов можно вставить *и говорит*.
Во втором же - нет.

Answer (score 2):

Неудачное оформление в обоих случаях.

Политолог Игорь Вершинин, говоря о том, что общество поровну разделилось между двумя векторами развития, в частности сказал: "Те, кто выступает за евразийский вектор, остались с чувством, что их воля была просто проигнорирована".

Политолог Игорь Вершинин, говоря о том, что общество поровну разделилось между двумя векторами развития, отметил: "Те, кто выступает за евразийский вектор, остались с чувством, что их воля была просто проигнорирована".